# No logro que me funcione el doble binding en un formulario de edición

Tags: angular, typescript, formularios, binding

Estoy intentando hacer doble binding entre un formulario de edición y unos elementos en la vista. Los elementos de la vista deberían de cambiar a medida que los voy editando desde el formulario, ósea intento hacer que se actualicen en tiempo real, pero no logro conseguirlo. Tengo dos componentes uno "experiencia" que es el componente padre y otro "item-experiencia" que es el componente hijo.
En la vista del componente padre tengo este código:

```
<div class="col-12 contenedor experiencia">
      <app-item-experiencia       
        (onEditExperiencia)="editExperiencia($event)">     
       </app-item-experiencia>              
    </div>
```

En la lógica del componente padre tengo este:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { ExperienciaService } from 'src/app/servicios/experiencia.service';
import { Experiencia } from 'src/app/experiencia';
import { UiExperienciaService } from 'src/app/servicios/ui-experiencia.service';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { EXPERIENCIA } from '../../mock'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-experiencia',
  templateUrl: './experiencia.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./experiencia.component.css'],
})
export class ExperienciaComponent implements OnInit {
  experiencias: Experiencia[] = [];
  constructor(   
    private experienciaService: ExperienciaService,
    private uiExperienciaService: UiExperienciaService
  ) {}
   
  experienciaLogo: string = '';
  experienciaTitulo: string = '';
  experienciaDescripcion: string = '';
  id: any = '';
 
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.experienciaService.getExperiencia().subscribe((experiencias) => {
      this.experiencias = experiencias;
    });
  }
  editExperiencia(experiencia: Experiencia) {
    this.experienciaService
      .actualizarExperiencia(experiencia)
      .subscribe((experiencia) => {
        this.experiencias.push(experiencia);
       
      });
  }
}
```

En la vista del componente hijo tengo esto:

```
<div
  class="list-group experiencia"
  *ngFor="let experiencia of experiencias"
  (onEliminarExperiencia)="eliminarExperiencia(experiencia)"
>
  <a
    href="#"
    class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex gap-3 py-3"
    aria-current="true"
  >
    <i class="{{ experiencia.experienciaLogo }}" style="font-size: 2em"></i>

    <div class="d-flex gap-2 w-100 justify-content-between">
      <div>
        <h6 class="mb-0">
          {{ experiencia.experienciaTitulo }}
        </h6>
        <p class="mb-0 opacity-75">
          {{ experiencia.experienciaDescripcion }}
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>

  <fa-icon
    [icon]="faTimes"    
    (click)="eliminarExperiencia(experiencia)"
  >
  </fa-icon>

  <fa-icon   
    [icon]="faPen"    
    (click)="toggleEditExperiencia(experiencia)"
    data-bs-toggle="modal"
    data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop"
  >
  </fa-icon>

  <div
    class="modal fade"
    id="staticBackdrop"
    data-bs-backdrop="static"
    data-bs-keyboard="false"
    tabindex="-1"
    aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel"
    aria-hidden="true"
  >
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">
            Editar Experiencia
          </h5>
          <button
            type="button"
            class="btn-close"
            data-bs-dismiss="modal"
            aria-label="Close"
          ></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form
            class="add-form"
            (ngSubmit)="onEditarSubmit()"
            #userForm="ngForm"
          >
            {{ userForm.value | json }}          

            <div class="form-control form-group">
              <label for="experienciaTitulo">Titulo</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                name="experienciaTitulo"
                id="experienciaTitulo"
                placeholder="Editar titulo"
                [(ngModel)]="experienciaTitulo"
              />
            </div>
            <div class="form-control">
              <label for="experienciaDescripcion">Descripcion</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                name="experienciaDescripcion"
                id="experienciaDescripcion"
                placeholder="Editar descripcion"
                [(ngModel)]="experienciaDescripcion"
              />
            </div>
            <div class="form-control">
              <label for="experienciaLogo">Logo</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                name="experienciaLogo"
                id="experienciaLogo"
                placeholder="Editar logo"
                [(ngModel)]="experienciaLogo"
              />
            </div>
            <div class="form-control">
              <label for="id">id </label>
              <input
                type="number"
                name="id"
                id="id"
                placeholder="id"
                [(ngModel)]="id"
              />
            </div>

            <input
              type="submit"
              value="Editar"
              class="btn btn-primary"
              data-bs-dismiss="modal"
            />
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**
El {{ userForm.value | json }} lo puse para ver si los valores se estaban actualizando y se actualizan correctamente en esa variable.
**
En la lógica del componente hijo tengo este código:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { EXPERIENCIA } from '../../mock';
import { Experiencia } from 'src/app/experiencia';
import { faTimes, faPen } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { ExperienciaService } from 'src/app/servicios/experiencia.service';
import { UiExperienciaService } from 'src/app/servicios/ui-experiencia.service';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-item-experiencia',
  templateUrl: './item-experiencia.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./item-experiencia.component.css'],
})
export class ItemExperienciaComponent implements OnInit {
  experiencias: Experiencia[] = [];
  @Output() onEditExperiencia: EventEmitter<Experiencia> = new EventEmitter();  
  faPen = faPen;
  faTimes = faTimes;
    
  subscription?: Subscription;
  experienciaTitulo: string = '';
  experienciaDescripcion: any = '';
  experienciaLogo: string = '';
  showEditExperiencia: boolean = false;
  id: any = ''; 

  constructor(
    private experienciaService: ExperienciaService,
    private uiExperienciaService: UiExperienciaService,    
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder
  ) {
      this.subscription = this.uiExperienciaService
      .onToggleA()
      .subscribe((value) => (this.showEditExperiencia = value));
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.experienciaService.getExperiencia().subscribe((experiencias) => {
      this.experiencias = experiencias;
    });
  }

  eliminarExperiencia(experiencia: Experiencia) {
    this.experienciaService.eliminarExperiencia(experiencia).subscribe(() => {
      this.experiencias = this.experiencias.filter(
        (t) => t.id !== experiencia.id
      );
    });
  }

  toggleEditExperiencia(experiencia: Experiencia) {
    this.experienciaService
      .experienciaGet(experiencia)
      .subscribe((experiencias) => {
        this.experiencias.filter((t) => t.id === experiencia.id);
        this.experienciaDescripcion = experiencia.experienciaDescripcion;
        this.experienciaTitulo = experiencia.experienciaTitulo;
        this.experienciaLogo = experiencia.experienciaLogo;
        this.id = experiencia.id;
      });
  }

  onEditarSubmit() {
    const { experienciaLogo, experienciaTitulo, experienciaDescripcion, id } =
      this;
    const editarExperiencia = {
      experienciaLogo,
      experienciaTitulo,
      experienciaDescripcion,
      id,
    };

    this.onEditExperiencia.emit(editarExperiencia);
  }
```

Por mas que le doy vueltas al problema no logro encontrar la solución. No se que puede estar fallando.

Comment: Leete este [blog](https://ofirrifo.medium.com/custom-angular-component-using-two-way-data-binding-aka-banana-in-a-box-syntax-9eb06b8cfb09), explica como usar el Two-Way Data Binding o tambien llamado "banana in a box" espero que te ayude, saludos.

Comment: Hola @AndresAbadia leí el blog e intente implementarlo pero sin suerte. Si agrego una etiqueta <input> a la vista si logro hacer el doble binding pero solo sobre ese campo, no hacia otro elemento como un <h6> o un <p> Además encontré que como estoy recorriendo un array con un ngFor para llamar a los distintos elementos tengo que llamarlos item.titulo por ejemplo, si pongo solo [(ngModel)]="titulo" no realiza el binding pero recorre el array ahora si pongo [(ngModel)]="item.titulo" si realiza el binding pero no recorre el array. Osea solo realiza el binding sobre el primer elemento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vi este hilo y te voy a intentar ayudar por aca. El doble binding con la directiva ngModel funciona dentro del mismo componente (entre la plantilla, generalmente un formulario, y el componente propiamente dicho, el codigo ts). Ahora para que esos cambios se vean reflejados en otro componente (componente padre), podes usar un emitter que emita los cambios, como has hecho vos en `EventEmitter<Experiencia>`, pero los cambios solo los vas a ver cuando el emisor emita y cambie la vista (en tu caso con un metodo asincrono en el componente padre).
Si los cambios los queres ver en el momento en que se estan rellenando los campos en el formulario, podes enviar una referencia del objeto que estas modificando desde el componente padre al hijo y realizar los cambios directamente en ese objeto, haciendo un binding del tipo [objeto_del_hijo]="objeto_del_padre" en la plantilla del padre (`<app-item-experiencia></app-item-experiencia>`), con su correspondiente `@Input()` en el componente hijo. Tene en cuenta que esto cambiara el objeto en el componente padre, aunque no hara uso del servicio (experienciaService), eso lo debes realizar al disparar el evento, como ya lo tenes (metodo editExperiencia). Espero haber podido ayudarte.